# Paperclip images failing to save in production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, production-environment

Im have just deployed a rails app which uses Paperclip to handle the file uploads to a linux ubuntu 10.04 server running apache2, passenger, rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3.

My setup worked perfectly fine in development, however now in production images never save.

i have commented out the following lines in production.rb so that rails deals with the file uploads and also tried using and installing XSendFile.

```
# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

and my picture.rb

```
attr_accessible :photo_file_name, :photo_file_size, :photo_content_type, :photo, :splash_image
  validates_presence_of :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size


  has_attached_file :photo,
    styles: {
      thumb: "150x150>"
    },
       url: "/assets/splash_images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
       path: ":rails_root/public/assets/splash_images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 25.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /image/
```

Does anyone know what could be going on? many thanks

Comment: Your run production on the same machine?

Comment: you mean localhost? nope this is on a linux vps server, I havent run the app in production mode on my local machine either

Comment: Can you post logs from production.log, when you upload file.

Comment: ah yes Meduza, from the logs rmagick has not been installed on the linux server! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Meduza and Hugo for pointing me in the right direction. To get the images uploading and saving successfully I had to install Imagemagick on the linux server and also give write permissions to the image path like so:

Append with sudo if not running from root

```
 apt-get install imagemagick
 apt-get install libmagick9-dev
 gem install rmagick

 chmod -R 777 app/app_name/public/assets/image_folder
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify paths if ImageMagick is not installed on the default paths. For windows users, do something like this in initializers/paperclip.rb:

> require "paperclip" require 'rbconfig' is_windows =
>   (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)
>
> Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\ImageMagick' if is_windows
>   Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false

find the location of "identify" in your imagemagick path and put that in here. Of course, you need to put the linux path in there. (/usr/bin/ ...)

Comment: hi Hugo, my path was good as you have mentioned I just didnt have any form of imagemagick installed! Also didnt have write permissions to the uploads folder!